# How to merge commands using execv? eg. ls | grep -c "expression"

Tags: bash, unix, execvp, execv, execl

I know I can do

```
execl("/bin/ls","-l",(char*)NULL)
```

to output ls.

But how do I execute

```
ls | grep -c "file"
```

using `execv`? In my code I want to search my current working directory for a particular file name. The above command returns 1 if the file exists and 0 if it doesn't. I want to execute this command from my program using `execv`. How do I do this?

I tried

```
execl("/bin/ls", "| grep -c file"  ,(char*)NULL)
```

But it doesn't work.

Also, even if I execute this command using `execl`, it will just print the output number in the terminal. How do I get it to return it to the program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pipes, dup2 and exec()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33884291/pipes-dup2-and-exec). Also you might want to look into `system(3)`.

Comment: That code isn't ever implemented as just one execv, unless you're using execv to invoke a shell that sets up pipes, forks, and calls a separate execv for each side of the pipeline.